# How to implement a sorted custom list class

Tags: java, list

So i have a class called `List` and a class called `SortedList` which inherits the class List. Also there is a class called node. I have created another class which contains the printing method.

But, everytime i insert three names for example, and i call the printing method it only prints the last name i have inserted. So my question is: does this code makes a sorted list? And if so, why does it print only the last name?

List class:

```
public class List {

    protected Node head;
    protected int length;

    public void list()
    {
        head=null;
        length=0;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return head==null;
    }
    public Node insert(Item a)
    {
        length++;
        head=new Node(a, head);
        return head;
    }
```

SortList class:

```
public class SortList extends List {

    private Node head;
    public SortList()
    {
        this.head=null;
    }
    public Node getFirst()
    {
        return head;
    }
    public Node Insert(Item newitem)
    {
        Node node = new Node(newitem);
        Node previous = null;
        Node current = head;
        while(current!=null && current.getValue().less(newitem))
        {
            previous=current;
            current=current.getNext();
        }
        if(previous==null)
        {
            head=node;
        }
        else
        {
            previous.setNext(node);
            node.setNext(current);
        }
        return head;
    }
    public void printlist()
{

    Node current = head; //ΑΡΧΗ ΤΗΣ ΛΙΣΤΑΣ.
    while(current!=null)
    {
        current.print();
        current = current.getNext();
    }
}
```

Node class:

```
public class Node {

    private Item info;
    private Node next;
    public Node(Item dat)
    {
        info=dat;
    }
    public Node (Item dat, Node b)
    {
        info=dat;
        next=b;
    }
    public Item getValue()
    {
        return info;
    }
    public void setNext(Node a)
    {
        next=a;
    }
    public Node getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }
    public void print()
    {
        info.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ You... must... use... Python...! Not... JAVA!

Comment: Why can't you use `Collections.sort()` on every change in the list's content?

Comment: Look at the constract of the List class `public void list()` it must be `public void List()`

Comment: Well thank you very much but i have to complete a project for my technical university and we have to use Java. So...

Comment: @Maria don't you get a nullpointerexception when trying to put the very first node inside the sortedlist?

Comment: No this has not appeared as a problem, yet.

Comment: and in SortList class, `Insert` method name is a typo (instead of `insert`)? because if not, it is not overriding, and you might be calling the insert of List instead of the insert of SortedList (which imho will give you the exception)

Comment: @Maria Why don't you use Lists in java.util.* `List<Node>` ??

Comment: No, it is not a typo. And in my main class i have created an object SortList list= new SortList(); And when i call it it's like list.Insert(....);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Implementation of `List`, you have a major bug in the `insert()` method:

```
public Node insert(Item a)
{
    length++;
    head=new Node(a, head);
    return head;
}
```

You do not attach the new element to the end of the list, but rather replace the list's head each time, thus discarding the previous element.

This would explain why you always only see the last element you have inserted.

**Edit:** Turns out, the `insert()` method actually does work, since you set the reference to the next node in the node's constructor.

In your sorted list however, you have one insert case for which the next node is not set:

```
if(previous==null)
{
    head=node;

}
```

I your sorted list, you don't set the next element in the constructor of the node. In all other cases, you set the next element in the `insert()` method, but not in this case. If the element you want to insert is the smallest in the list, `previous` is null, which is correct -- your new element is the new `head` of the list. Since you don't set the new element's successor, however, all elements that have been in the list are now gone.

If the last element you insert into the list is the smallest, the last element will also be the only one remaining and you print out only the last element.

Try setting the successor:

```
if(previous==null)
{
    head=node;
    head.setNext(current);
}
```

Comment: mmh, the head maybe should be renamed tail... but it should still work becuase the reference is not discarded, the current head reference will be next for the new head

Comment: Ok, i understand what you say but can you be more specific? Can you give me an example or the correct code?

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ is actually right, your code should work. I just missed that the reference to the next element is set inside the constructor of the new `Node`. My Bad!